# Xpath select specific list elements

Tags: html, xpath

Hey I have following html:

```html
<ul>
<li><strong>Telefon:</strong></li>
<li>211 600</li>
<li>330 233</li>
<li><strong>Fax:</strong></li>
<li>336 884</li>
<li><strong>e-mail:</strong></li>
<li>test@vdsaadm.xx</li>
</ul>
```

My question is how would one select 2 phone numbers in a case where u dont know if next li element with bold text is "FAX:" or if next li element even exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to get the text content of any `li` elements whose preceding sibling is an `li` whose text content is `Telefon:` but which don’t have a preceding sibling whose text content is `Fax:`:

```
//ul/li[preceding-sibling::li[.='Telefon:']][not((self::li|preceding-sibling::li)[.='Fax:'])]/text()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//ul/li/text()
```

this will return a list of text under `li` tag, you can use slice to get the phone number

out:

```
Text = 211 600
Text = 330 233
Text = 336 884
Text = test@vdsaadm.xx
```